# Laravel raw query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I've tested the following query in mysql:

```
select a.name,l.name,al.count from artikel as a inner join 
artikel_location as al on a.id=al.artikel_id inner join location
as l on l.id=al.location_id
```

The output is what I would expect. But when I run this in laravel like this:

```
$products = DB::select( DB::raw("select a.name,l.name,al.count from artikel as a inner join 
                                        artikel_location as al on a.id=al.artikel_id inner join location
                                        as l on l.id=al.location_id") );
dd(json_encode($products));
```

The a.name field is gone? Why is that?

Comment: laravel use only the name of a column not the table name.
You can use aliases as a workaround.

Comment: @Fiete Could you give an example?

Comment: `select a.name as a_name, l.name as l_name ,al.count as al_count`.

Comment: @Fiete thanks that solved my problem.

Comment: @Fele . . . You should add that as an answer so jamie can accept it.